# GeoIP on wordpress, ( not working )

Tags: php, geoip

I am trying to show a specific content base on the user Country IP, when doing a search i have found the below script. But without success! So what i am trying to do is when a user visit my website ( in this case: "AL" ) to not show this content.

```
<?php
require_once("geoip.inc");
$gi = geoip_open("GeoIP.dat",GEOIP_STANDARD);
$country_code = geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
geoip_close($gi);
if($country_code == "AL")
{
echo ' ';
} else {
echo '
<div id="sendframe" style="position: absolute; opacity:1.0;filter:alpha(opacity=1);">

//Here will be placed the comment...

</div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: And this isn't working... **HOW**?

Comment: I have done some tests in all 3-three of my websites and on all of them is **not working**. Maybe something is blocking the geoip, not sure for this

Comment: That still doesn't tell us anything. Are you getting syntax errors? server crashing? incorrect results? no results?

Comment: Can you `var_dump($country_code);` ?

Comment: @MarcB i do not have any error, no server crashing, and the result is the same the content still is showing.

Comment: @ShankarDamodran i just tried as you suggested, result the same, without success.